# Google signin and facebook connect work fine on desktop, not on mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-signin

I have added sign google 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/
and facebook connection to my application with facebook JS SKD.

**This works great on desktop.** However when I click on connect button on my mobile (chrome browser), **nothing happens**:

http://www.culture-generale.fr/jeu-quiz/

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: No errors :in fact new browser window does not open. It work fine on Android phone but not on iPhone. Looks like iPhone prevents new window.